# PhoneGap Jquery Bad Sliding

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have developped a phonegap application for android with jQuery mobile , and finally I find myself in front of mobile application with awesome interfaces and very bad sliding between pages , I tried all type of sliding 'none' 'pop' .... but the same result and espacially when I push the back button .If there is no solution to this I will be obliged to make java application with no jquery .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same errors:

```
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){

// Disable transitions between pages. Android performance in transitions is very poor.
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none'; //fade o slidefade
// Gets rid of the back problem
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
});
```

I used this code and my slides were perfect just like in "Java Application"